# how to update an webpage based on the imput from that same webpage with only html and js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

my plan is to create a webserver (via node.js), where you can input a suggestion for a date (featuring date, time, activity and who posted it) and a separate list with possible activities. 
My problem now is, that the webserver seems to refresh itself in the beginning after I submitted input as well as when I change the input.

I tried it like this:
       `<html>
          <body>
            <div class="listing">
              <table id="calendar">
                <tr>
                  <th> Date </th>
                  <th> Time </th>
                  <th> Activity </th>
                  <th> Proposer </th>
                </tr>
            </div>
         </html>`

```
 <script>
    function updatingCalendar() {
    var datum = document.getElementById('Datum').value;
    var uhrzeit = document.getElementById('Uhrzeit').value;
    var beschaeftigung = document.getElementById('beschaeftigung').value;
    var table = document.getElementById("calendar");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = datum;          //means date
    cell2.innerHTML = uhrzeit;        //means time
    cell3.innerHTML = beschaeftigung; //means activity
    cell4.innerHTML = name;           //means mame/proposer
  } 

  var name;
  function nameToAnybody () {
    name = "Anybody";
  }
  function nameToSomebody() {
    name = "Somebody";
  }

  var activityList = 2;
  function updatingActivityList () {
    var newActivity = document.getElementById("newActivity").value;
    if (activityList === 2) {
        activityList = newActivity;
    } else {
      activityList = activityList + ", "+ newActivity;
    }
    var y = document.getElementById("activityList");
    y.innerHTML = activityList;
  }
</script>

     <div class="inputForDate">
    <form>
    Datum: <input type="date" id='Datum' name="date" value='2019-12-24'> <br>
    Uhrzeit: <input type="time" id='Uhrzeit' value='22:00'> <br>
    Besch&#228;ftigung: <br> <input type="text" id='beschaeftigung' name="activity"> <br> 
    Wer bist du? <input type="radio" name="name" value="Anybodyy" onclick="nameToAnybody()"> anybody  
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="Somebody" onclick="nameToSomebody()"> Somebody <br> <br>
    <button onclick="updatingCalendar()"> submit </button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="listing">
  <p id="activityList"> possible activities </p>
</div>

<div class="inputForActivities">
  <h1 class="headline"> Whats missing?</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Was sollten wir mal machen?" id="newActivity"> <br> <br>
    <button onclick="updatingActivityList()"> submit </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

but it only works when I comment out column 3 and only when I do not change the input I give.

I also tried this:

```
  function creatingCalendar() {
      var table = document.getElementById("calendar");
      for (i = 0, i<names.length, i++) {
        var rows = table.insertRow(i);

        for (j = 0, j<4, j++) {
          var d = rows.insertCell(j);
          d.id= "r" + i + "c" + j;
        }}

    function updatingArrays (newEntry, array) {
      array.push(newEntry);
    }


    function newDate(){
        var newDate = document.getElementById('Datum').value;
        updatingArrays(newDate, dates);
        for (x = 0, x<dates.length, x++) {
          idCount = "r" + x + "c0";
          cell1 = document.getElementById("idCount");
          cell1.innerHTML = dates[x];
        }
      }

        function updatingCalendar() {
          creatingCalendar();
          newDate();
      }
```

I also tried to do it with an clickCount:

```
      var dates = [];

      function updatingArrays (newEntry, array) {
          array.push(newEntry);
        }

        function updatingCalendar() {   
        var datum = document.getElementById('Datum').value;
        updatingArrays (datum, dates);
var uhrzeit = document.getElementById('Uhrzeit').value;
        var beschaeftigung = document.getElementById('beschaeftigung').value;
        var table = document.getElementById("calendar");
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = datum[clickCount];
        cell2.innerHTML = 'uhrzeit';
        cell3.innerHTML = 'beschaeftigung';
        cell4.innerHTML = 'name';
        clickCount++;
        }
```

As u might see, I only tried it with the 'datum' one, left out changes for the others

I mostly want to know why it is that the webserver is refreshing. Here - if needed - the server-code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {   
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html' })
  fs.readFile('../bla3.html', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(404)
      res.write('Error: File Not Found')
    } else {
      res.write(data)
    }
    res.end()
  })
})

server.listen(port, function(error) {                 
if (error) {
  console.log('Something went wrong', error)
} else {
  console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port)
}

})
```

Comment: What, exactly, does "the webserver seems to refresh itself" mean?

Comment: Not exactly sure either of the problem you are having but here is one noticeable issue: activityList === 2, the first time the function is called that will be evaluated as true since activityList is declared 2. Unless it was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Because you using button inside `<form>` - it fires your function, than `submit` of the form. To prevent it, you need to add:

```
    <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return false;">
```